# Unhandled Error returned in Promise Rejection (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

So, I am not really new when it comes to USING Promises. I understand and have used `.then(), .catch(), Promise.all()` before. I used them chiefly to fetch API calls.

However, I am a complete beginner when it comes to CREATING my own promises.

So, I was attempting to create my own promise and the `reject()` function kept on giving me the `unhandled error (my rejection message)` message. Although, the `resolve()` function worked as expected.

Here is my **(simplified)** codes:

```
const request = require('request-promise');

return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        /*
         * Some other codes that might throw other exceptions
         */
        ....
        ....

        const options = "ASSUME THIS IS A CALL TO A THIRD-PARTY API";

        await request(options)
            .then((val: any) => {
                ...
                // I had no issue with this. Resolve returns properly
                resolve(val);                     
            })
            .catch((e: any) => {
                ...

                // I would need to translate the error message from this 
                // Third-Party API. But, this reject function keeps on 
                // returning me an "unhandled error" issue
                reject(translateMsg(e.message, "fr"));
            });
    }
    catch(err) {
        reject("Oops other errors detected");
    }
}
```

*Note: This error message was shown in my Firebase Function's log. I am not sure if the issue lies in my codes or somewhere else.*

Thank you!

(EDIT 1)
I did some other processing (translation, etc.) in the `request.catch()` statement. So, I need to return a new Error message and not the default `e` object.

(EDIT 2)
Assume that `translateMsg()` is well-tested and it ALWAYS returns a string.

Comment: Here `request` is already returning a promise. why are you creating Promise over another Promise?

Comment: Whatever is using this promise you created apparently doesn’t handle rejections then…?

Comment: @palaѕн There are actually some codes that I didn't paste here for brevity sake. So, there are some other codes in the `request.then() ` and `request.catch()`. I was trying to process the result of the request and return a new Promise

Comment: @deceze I am using this npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) for `request()` and based on the documentation, it does handle rejection.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your API already returns a promise, there is absolutely no reason to create one of your own.  Just use the one you have.  Also, mixing async/await with then/catch is rarely advisable.

Honestly, the best course of action is not to add anything at all.  Just `return request(options)`, and the caller will receive and promise that already resolves or rejects on its own.

If you absolutely must change what the call receives in terms of resolution or rejection, what you're doing can be simplified down to:

```
const options = "ASSUME THIS TO BE AN API CALL";
try {
    const val = await request(options)
    // maybe you want to change val here?  Return what you want.
    return val
}
catch (err) {
    throw "Oops other errors detected"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! The code snippet I gave above might be over-simplified. The outermost try-catch block was there to catch the other errors that were thrown by the codes above the `const options`. The inner catch block is to catch that error from a third-party API, which I don't have access to.  I would need to return the translated error message instead of the original error message of that API call. I think I will just move my `request(option)` codes to another async function, which I can call from here. That way, my codes would be more readable.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for pointing out that "mixing async/await with then/catch" is an antipattern, After revisiting the Firebase Function documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), I just realised that errors in Firebase should be returned this way `throw new functions.https.HttpsError("")`. I will still mark this as accepted answer as you have pointed out some of the best practices.

Comment: It would have been more clear if you showed the entire function in the question, especially the fact that you were using a callable type function.  Not all types of functions work the same way.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, thanks guys for pointing out all of the best practices when it comes to handling promises. I am going to fix my codes accordingly.

My issue turned out to be originated from the **Google Firebase Function** I was using.

Upon revisiting the documentation, I realised that the proper way to handle an error in Firebase Function is by throwing `throw new functions.https.HttpsError("")` and not `Promise.reject()`.

Thanks again!

[image: Firebase Function Error Handling]

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable